# Why recursive async functions require 'static parameters in Rust?

Tags: rust, async-await

Given a simple async function:

```
async fn foo(n: usize) -> usize {
    if n > 0 { foo(n - 1).await }
    else { 0 }
}
```

The compiler complains that `async fn` must be rewritten to return a boxed `dyn Future`.

```
| async fn foo(n: usize) -> usize {
|                           ^^^^^ recursive `async fn`
  = note: a recursive `async fn` must be rewritten to return a boxed `dyn Future`.

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0733`.
```

---

Compiler explanation (`rustc --explain E0733`):

To achieve async recursion, the `async fn` needs to be desugared
such that the `Future` is explicit in the return type:

```
use std::future::Future;
fn foo_desugared(n: usize) -> impl Future<Output = ()> {
    async move {
        if n > 0 {
            foo_desugared(n - 1).await;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, the future is wrapped in a pinned box:

```
use std::future::Future;
use std::pin::Pin;
fn foo_recursive(n: usize) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = ()>>> {
    Box::pin(async move {
        if n > 0 {
            foo_recursive(n - 1).await;
        }
    })
}
```

The `Box<...>` ensures that the result is of known size,
and the pin is required to keep it in the same place in memory.

---

Now consider this code:

```
fn foo(n: &usize) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = usize>>> {
    Box::pin(async move {
        if *n > 0 {
            foo(&n).await
        } else {
            0
        }
    })
}
```

The compiler complains that the lifetime of `&n` should be `'static`.

```
|   fn foo(n: &usize) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = usize>>> {
|             ------ help: add explicit lifetime `'static` to the type of `n`: `&'static usize`
| /     Box::pin(async move {
| |         if *n > 0 {
| |             foo(&n).await
| |         } else {
| |             0
| |         }
| |     })
| |______^ lifetime `'static` required
```

**Please help me understand what is going on**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trait objects (`dyn Trait`) will by default have a static lifetime, unless otherwise specified. Because of this, boxed futures (and other traits) without a specified lifetime cannot depend on borrowed data, unless that data is borrowed for the `'static` lifetime. (Which is what your error message complains about).

To solve this, you can either specify the lifetime explicitly, or you can just use `'_`, in which case it will use the elided lifetime of the `n: &usize` parameter:

```rust
//        .--  will use elided lifetime from here
//        v                      v--  give the future a non-'static lifetime
fn foo(n: &usize) -> Pin<Box<dyn '_ + Future<Output = usize>>> {
// or: fn foo<'a>(n: &'a usize) -> Pin<Box<dyn 'a + Future<Output = usize>>>
    Box::pin(async move {
        if *n > 0 {
            foo(&n).await // <-- no error, as the future lifetime now depends on the
                          //     lifetime of n instead of having a 'static lifetime
        } else {
            0
        }
    })
}
```