# Can I use await inside async recursive functions?

Tags: rust

```
pub async fn send_and_expect(&mut self, request: rtsp_types::Request<Body>, retrying: bool) -> std::result::Result<rtsp_types::Response<Body>, ClientActionError> {
```

I get:

```
recursion in an `async fn` requires boxing
    
recursive `async fn`
    
note: a recursive `async fn` must be rewritten to return a boxed `dyn Future`rustc(E0733)
```

I found https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/07_workarounds/04_recursion.html but it is for a function that does not use `async`.

What should be the way here?

I found [Why recursive async functions require 'static parameters in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59538812/why-recursive-async-functions-require-static-parameters-in-rust) and I changed my function to

```
pub fn send_and_expect(&mut self, request: rtsp_types::Request<Body>, retrying: bool) 
-> Pin<Box<dyn Future <Output = std::result::Result<rtsp_types::Response<Body>, ClientActionError>>>> {
```

but now I cannot use `await` inside my funtion. Also, how do I return things?

For example:

```
return Box::pin(Err(ClientActionError::CSeqMissing))
```

won't work

**UPDATE**:

Based on the answer, below, I get this on the recursion call:

```
194 |         }.boxed()
    |           ^^^^^ future created by async block is not `Send`
    |
    = help: the trait `std::marker::Send` is not implemented for `dyn futures::Future<Output = std::result::Result<rtsp_types::Response<Body>, ClientActionError>>`
note: future is not `Send` as it awaits another future which is not `Send`
   --> src/client.rs:170:36
    |
170 | ...                   return self.send_and_expect(request.clone(), true).await;
    |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ await occurs here on type `Pin<Box<dyn futures::Future<Output = std::result::Result<rtsp_types::Response<Body>, ClientActionError>>>>`, which is not `Send`
```

**UPDATE 2:**

```
error[E0759]: `self` has an anonymous lifetime `'_` but it needs to satisfy a `'static` lifetime requirement
   --> src/client.rs:156:20
    |
154 |       pub fn send_and_expect(&mut self, request: rtsp_types::Request<Body>, retrying: bool) 
    |                              --------- this data with an anonymous lifetime `'_`...
155 |       -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = std::result::Result<rtsp_types::Response<Body>, ClientActionError>>+ Send>> {    
156 |           async move {
    |  ____________________^
157 | |             let expected_cseq_header_value = rtsp_types::HeaderName::from_static_str("cseq").unwrap();
158 | |             let expected_cseq = request.header(&expected_cseq_header_value);
159 | |             let expected_cseq = match expected_cseq {
...   |
193 | |             Err(ClientActionError::Teardown)
194 | |         }.boxed()
    | |_________^ ...is captured here, requiring it to live as long as `'static`
    |
help: to declare that the trait object captures data from argument `self`, you can add an explicit `'_` lifetime bound
    |
155 |     -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = std::result::Result<rtsp_types::Response<Body>, ClientActionError>>+ Send + '_>> {    
    |                                                                                                              ^^^^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I found [...] but it is for a function that does not use `async`.

Yes it does. You should take a closer look at code. The original function is definitely `async`:

```
async fn recursive() {
    recursive().await;
    recursive().await;
}
```

> ... but now I cannot use `await` inside my function.

You can if you make an `async {}` block as the fix suggests:

```
use futures::future::{BoxFuture, FutureExt};

fn recursive() -> BoxFuture<'static, ()> {
    async move {
        recursive().await; // you can use await here
        recursive().await;
    }.boxed()
}
```

The idea is simply async return type needs to be boxed instead of an `impl Future`. So the fix is to create an `async {}` block, wherein you run your function as normal, and then box it in order to return it. This avoids the issue caused by nested `async`/`await` functions being monomorphised together.

So you should be able to:

```
pub fn send_and_expect(&mut self, request: rtsp_types::Request<Body>, retrying: bool) 
-> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = std::result::Result<rtsp_types::Response<Body>, ClientActionError>> + Send>> {
                                                                                                // ^^^^^^
    async move {
        // put your original code here
    }.boxed()
}
```

> Also, how do I return things?

You can return things as normal, either via the last expression in the `async` block, or you can use `return`. You should simply the same as you would for a proper `async` function, don't worry about the `Box::pin(...)`.

If you need the `Future` to satisfy any other trait bounds (`Send`, `Sync`, `Unpin`, etc.) then you can specify it along with the `dyn Future<...>`

---

The return type requires `dyn Future<Output = ...> + Send` to use `.boxed()`.

If the contents of the `async` block cannot be made `Send`, you can do it manually like so (although most runtimes expect `Future`s to be `Send` so you'd have a hard time using it):

```
fn recursive() -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = ()>>> {
    Box::pin(async move {
        recursive().await;
        recursive().await;
    })
}
```

Comment: I get `future created by async block is not `Send`

help: the trait `std::marker::Send` is not implemented for `dyn futures::Future<Output = std::result::Result<rtsp_types::Response<body::Body>, client::ClientActionError>>``

Comment: @Gatonito my apologies, I've updated the post to highlight that `+ Send` is needed in the return type.

Comment: please look at my update. By requiring it to be `Send`, then I get problems with lifetime of `self`. I guess that now it knows that I might want to send this to other threads, so it can't ensure that self lives enough. Even though self is captured by the async, I don't use it on the return result. Isn't there a way to fix this?

Comment: @Gatonito Does my last paragraph and code sample not help in that case? If not, you'll probably have to provide more code in your question.

Comment: I'm confused in how your last conde helps. It takes off the `&mut self`, and what is the difference between `Box::pin` and `.boxed()`?

Answer (score 0):

Also, in hopes that it'll help somebody else, there's a crate providing a macro to do the whole complicated function rewrite automatically: https://docs.rs/async-recursion/latest/async_recursion.